# I cant figure out how to expand my code

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I need to filter the data in my database. using a text box. 
in my application. I use 4 text boxes (User,PC,IP and Asset). i want to use those boxes to filter data if its already existed in my database.
I have this code working but it work only for one text box. 
can you help me to expand this code. so i be able to filter all my data using all 4 text boxes?

```
SQL.RunQuery("SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.User = '" & txtUser.Text & "'")
    If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("already exists!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Dim stmt As String = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE members.User = '" & txtUser.Text & "'"

if Not txtPC.text.trim.length = 0 then
    stmt = stmt & " AND members.PC = '" & txtPC.Text & "'"
End If
if Not txtIP.text.trim.length = 0 then
    stmt = stmt & " AND members.IP = '" & txtIP.Text & "'"
End If
if Not txtAsset.text.trim.length = 0 then
    stmt = stmt & " AND members.Asset = '" & txtAsset.Text & "'"
End If

SQL.RunQuery(stmt)
If SQL.SQLDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox("already exists!")
    Exit Sub
Else
    ....
End If
```

But I **strictly suggest** you to use [SqlCommand.Prepare Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare(v=vs.110).aspx) as your current query is exposed to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: I'l try this one and also the Sqlcommand.Prepare Method. Thanks